# Burnout Paradise addons for PC

Tags: pc, steam, burnout-paradise, mods

I'm thinking about buying *Burnout Paradise: The Ultimate Box* on Steam. I also want the addons to the game, such as *Big Surf Island* and *Cops and Robbers*. Are they available for PC or only for consoles? Are there any addons available for PC?

Comment: Big Surf Island would be great to have, but it's a nice game anyway =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They were all finally released for PC with the Remaster version in 2018.**

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately no add-ons for us, second class (pc) gamers.

Answer (score 1):

The list of game-changing content released to Burnout Paradise is available at this wiki:

http://burnout.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Changing_Content

In that page, there is a table that shows what kind of content is not available on PC.

Also, the "Burnout Paradise: The Ultimate Box" includes the Bikes addon (and maybe one or two updates too), but it has a bug that won't let you change the colors of the extra unlocked bikes. This is a known bug and was fixed in Big Surf Island update. However, since Criterion Games won't bring that update to PC, we're stuck with that bug forever. :-(

I'd add a link to the actual bug report, but [Criterion Games Bugzilla](http://www.criteriongames.com/bugzilla/) has changed the address and now requires login.

Although the console version has more updates and more content, the PC version is still good. On the other hand, given the choice, it's probably better to pick the console version.